# What is the finite element displacement function for a trapeze?

Tags: elasticity

As you may know for a rectangle with 4 nodes we can express the displacement function for each displacement component as the following:
$$u=a_1+a_2 \cdot X+a_3 \cdot Y+a_4\cdot X\cdot Y$$
$$v=b_1+b_2\cdot X+b_3 \cdot Y+b_4\cdot X\cdot Y$$
Where u is the horizontal component of the displacement function of a trapeze, v is the vertical component of the displacement function of a trapeze and epsilon X is strain in the X direction.
Please keep in mind that I am not familiar with finite element method, i was trying to solve a problem in theory of elasticity and needed to find displacement function for a trapeze. 
My question is that is the displacement function of a trapeze similar to the displacement function of a rectangle with 4 nodes or there is an other displacement function for a trapeze?
If yes, using the same formula i am trying to get the strain components, but u becomes something like:
$$u=4\cdot 10^{-4}\cdot X-1.36\cdot 10^{-3} \cdot Y+4\cdot 10^{-4} \cdot X \cdot Y$$
the problem is that in derivation respect to X, "Y" does not get eliminated from the function, therefore i am not able to obtain epsilon X i.e., epsilon X is not numerical. As far as i know, the strain components of a shape are numerical, so i should obtain a number for epsilon X.
Please give me some hints on the displacement function of a trapeze.

Comment: You should provide more information and clarify your notation. What is the context of your question? What is your $u$, $v$, and $\epsilon_X$? Why does it have to be a single number?

Comment: @Semoi, I am asking about horizontal and vertical components of the displacement function of a trapeze where u is the horizontal component and v is the vertical component. ϵX is strain in the X direction and it has to be a number because there is a displacement in the X axis which is numerical and the displacement over the initial length describes the strain definition. (If i am wrong, let me know.)